# Map Object to String using Typescript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I have the classes:

```
interface Post {
  id: number;
  tags: Tag[];
}

interface Tag {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

I need to convert an array of posts to an array of posts models:

```
interface PostModel {
  postId: number;
  tagsNames: string[];
}
```

I tried the following:

```
let postModels : PostModel[] = posts.map((post: Post) => { 

  return {
    postId: post.id, 
    tagNames: post.tags.map((tag: Tag) => tag.name)
  };

});
```

But I get the error:

```
Type '{ id: number; tagNames: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'PostModel'.   
Property 'tagsNames' is missing in type '{ id: number; tagsNames: string[]; }'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Um change `tagNames` to `tagsNames` in the body of the map.. The error is pretty clear as far as TS errors go :)

Comment: Ah missed that! Damm ... Thank you.